# Zabbix server upgrade issue

Tags: zabbix

We are unable to upgrade the zabbix version to 4.4.. there seems to be an error with upgrading Database. Could someone help on this:

```
[Z3005] query failed: [1005] Can't create table 'zabbix.#sql-179d_144bb0' (errno: 135) [alter table `hosts` add `proxy_address` varchar(255) default '' not null]
```

This  error is shown in logs. I tried to give privileges to zabbix user but no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got resolved. 
The FS where database is stored has 100% utilization. Extending the FS resolved the issue.